# Create arrow heads in spotfire using python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

Does Spotfire supports creating custom lines and arrowheads?
I have tried creating vector using mat plot library

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. You can write visualization Mods in Spotfire but that is not related to Python libraries.